# Rewrite regex to accept conditional terms

Tags: javascript, regex

```
^([a-z0-9_\.-])+@[yahoo]{5}\.([com]{3}\.)?[com]{3}$
```

this currently matches xxxx@yahoo.com , how can I rewrite this to match some additional domains? for example, gmail.com and deadforce.com. I tried the following but it did not work, what am I doing wrong?

```
^([a-z0-9_\.-])+@[yahoo|gmail|deadforce]{5,9}\.([com]{3}\.)?[com]{3}$
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are tons of answers about validating email addresses with regex.

Comment: You flagged the question both "javascript" and "php" - which is it?  Also see http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex doesn't say what you think it says.

```
^([a-z0-9_\.-])+@[yahoo]{5}\.([com]{3}\.)?[com]{3}$
```

Says any characters `a-z`, `0-9`, `.`, `-` one or more times.

That later part where you are trying match `yahoo.com` is incorrect. It says `y`, `a`, `h`, or `o`, any of those characters are allowed 5 times. Same with the `com` so `aaaaa.ooo` would be valid here. I'm not sure what the `([com]{3}\.)?[com]{3}` was trying to say but I presume you wanted to check for `.com`.

See character classes documentation here, http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.

What you want is

```
^([a-z0-9_.\-])+@yahoo\.com$
```

or for more domains use grouping,

```
^([a-z0-9_.\-])+@(yahoo|gmail|deadforce)\.com$
```

<s>You haven't stated what language you are using so a real demo can't be given.</s>

Functional demo, https://jsfiddle.net/qa9x9hua/1/

Comment: I've added a demo per your JS specification. If you have questions please post.

Answer (score 0):

Email validation is a notoriously difficult problem, and many people have failed quite horribly at trying to validate them themselves.

Filter var has a filter just for emails. Use that to check for email address validity. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

```
if (filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // Email is valid
}
```

There's probably no downside to doing the domain check the easy way. Just check for the domain strings in the email address. e.g.

```
if (
    filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) &&
    preg_match("/@(yahoo|gmail|deadforce)\.com/", $email)
) {
    // Email is valid
}
```

In terms of your original regular expression, quite a lot of it was incorrect, which is why you were having trouble changing it. 
[regexper](http://regexper.com/#%5E(%5Ba-z0-9_%5C.-%5D)%2B%40%5Byahoo%5D%7B5%7D%5C.(%5Bcom%5D%7B3%7D%5C.)%3F%5Bcom%5D%7B3%7D%24) shows what you've created.

```
([a-z0-9_\.-])+ should be [a-z0-9_\.-]+ or ([a-z0-9_\.-]+)
```

The () are only capturing results in this section. If you want results move the brackets, if not remove them.

```
[yahoo]{5} should be yahoo
```

That's matching 5 characters that are one of y,a,h,o so it would match hayoo etc.

```
\.([com]{3}\.)?[com]{3} should be \.com
```

Dunno what this was trying to accomplish but you only wanted .com

Take a look at http:// www.regular-expressions.info /tutorial.html for a guide to regular expressions